# Wildfly Maven Plugin ignores deployment name?

Tags: wildfly, maven-plugin, wildfly-8

I added the `name` parameter on my deployment using Wildfly Maven Plugin:

```
mvn wildfly:deploy -Dname=myapp  -Dwildfly.hostname=myserver -Dwildfly.username=user -Dwildfly.password=pwd
```

However, it keeps on deploying with the Maven version and extension.
Here's how it looks in standalone.xml

```
<deployment name="myapp-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war" runtime-name="myapp-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war">
    <content sha1="17e09de2cd8f78ffd033a90b4e82bdb52eb9485b"/>
</deployment>
```

The reason is to streamline the deployment process. After a Maven release, the deployment name changes to `myapp-1.1.war`, and the new development becomes `myapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war`.  Instead of undeploying release `myapp-1.1.war`, and deploying `myapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war`, we want to reduce it to a single step - just redeploy `myapp`, and it should overwrite the old one.

Btw, if I just deploy, I'll have the two versions.

Just to be clear, this is the goal:

```
<deployment name="myapp" runtime-name="myapp-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war">
    <content sha1="17e09de2cd8f78ffd033a90b4e82bdb52eb9485b"/>
</deployment>
```

This seems like a very simple case, and it should work as per the documentation:  https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the name parameter on the via the command line. You'd need to add a configuration property for the name configuration parameter and override that on the command line.

```xml
...
<properties>
    <deployment.name>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</deployment.name>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha7</version>
    <configuration>
        <name>${deployment.name}</name>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Then on the command you could use `-Ddeployment.name=myapp`. One note though is you'll want to use the appropriate file extension, e.g. `.war`, so the deployment will be processed properly.

Comment: Following what you said, I can change the deployment name now, but the runtime-name always copies the name.  I've tried different combinations, but still not working.  I want the version to remain in the runtime-name.  Similar to what was stated in the doc:  https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html#runtimeName  Thanks again in advance, and I appreciate your quick replies.

Comment: Are you specifying the `<runtime-name/>` configuration property or using the `wildfly.deployment.runtime.name` command line property? If not the runtime-name will default to the deployment name.

Comment: I have this in my pom.xml:  
<properties>
   <deployment.name>A</deployment.name>
   <runtime.name>B</runtime.name>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <skip>false</skip>
      <name>${deployment.name}</name>
      <runtime-name>${runtime.name}</runtime-name>      
   </configuration>
...
runtime name is not respected. It copies the deployment name
   <deployment name="A" runtime-name="A">            
      <content sha1="..."/>
           </deployment>

Comment: What version of the plugin?

Comment: wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final

Comment: I tried it on version 1.1.0.Final and it works fine.  Thanks! :-)